# Wallet pass fails to display if it has no images

Tags: passbook, wallet

I am trying to create an ios Wallet Event Ticket. I managed to give all the info I needed to create the pass.json and I have signed and zipped it. When I try to open this on a Mac, I am able to see the pass in the preview. When I email it and try to open it from an iPhone, the screen just goes to the main screen as if it crashed.

After lots of experimentation I found out that if I add at least one of t he images (icon) I am able to see it in preview and add it to the Wallet.

Since I do not care to add any image, this seems way too much just to make it work.

The question is, are images required in the pass? And if not, why does it not work without them. I repeat, it was displayed on Mac preview either with or without the image file.

Comment: Please read the documentation - an icon image is mandatory.

Comment: @passkit, Please add a link and make it an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @PassKit where exactly in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/PackageStructure.html) is this defined? I fail to see a mention of how the icon is mandatory.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes! manifest.json required the image correctly**, moreover the pass.json also need to ensure everything is correct. Some elements must add in json for iPhone open, for example:serialNumber, webServiceURL, authenticationToken, relevantDate

Also, **iPhone open .pkpass as difference format with mac.** In my case , the signature file is wrong will also make the .pkpass file cannot open in iPhone.